# CMake's find packages finds nonexisting python library

Tags: python, cmake, anaconda

FindPythonLibs.cmake is somehow finding Python versions that don't exist/were uninstalled.

When I run `find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)` CMake properly finds my Python3.6 installation and adds its include path, but then I get the error

`No rule to make target 'C:/Users/ultim/Anaconda2/libs/python27.lib', needed by 'minotaur-cpp.exe'.  Stop.`

This directory doesn't exist, and I recently uninstalled Anaconda and the python that came with it. I've looked through my environment variables and registry, but find no reference to this location.

Would anyone know where there might still be a reference to this location?

Comment: Have you tried to remove build directory and run `cmake` again?

Comment: This sure would be a nice question to get an answer to

Answer (score 0):

Since the "REQUIRED" option to `find_package()` is not working, you can be explicit about which Python library using CMake options with cache variables:

`cmake -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Python36\include -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=C:\Python36\libs\python36.lib ..`